How to correctly and elegant implement the apply function for structured binding?
In the std namespace, there is a convenient std::apply function that allows you to perform an action on each element of the tuple. Using structured binding, we can achieve the same behavior for non-tuple types. Suppose we consider a type with only one non-static data member. Therefore, I wrote the following code:
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<class F, class T>
decltype(auto) apply1(F&& func, T&& val){
    if constexpr(std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(val)>{}){
        auto& [m1] = val;
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), m1);
    }   else {
        auto&& [m1] = std::forward<T>(val);
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<decltype(m1)>(m1));
    }
}
//tests
struct obj{int v;};
struct data{obj o;};
void ref(obj&){std::cout<<"&\n";}
void cref(const obj&){std::cout<<"const&\n";}
void temp(obj&&){std::cout<<"&&\n";}

int main(){
    data d{};
    apply1(ref, d);
    apply1(cref, d);
   //SHOULD NOT COMPILE apply1(temp, d);
    apply1(temp, std::move(d));
}

As you can see, the apply1 function has branching depending on the type of reference and therefore looks strange. But without this, the above tests will not work
Q: Is it possible to write the apply1 in a more elegant way without using branching? but at the same time, the above tests should work

Could you please extend the question and explain why you need a separate branch for lvalue reference?

@Eugene Without a branch, the above tests will not work. Otherwise, I do not know how to rewrite this function so that there is no branching and the tests work

Wait for C++23's std::forward_like and then do auto& [m1] = val; std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), std::forward_like<T>(m1));.

I compiled and disassembled your example code. AFAICT, the disassembly has no conditional branches in it. So, maybe, no worries? IMO, it's the asm code to look at for conditional jumps. Some background: how to do right shift rounding middle towards even In that, I have an answer that shows disassembly and benchmarking (i.e. code with if or ternary operator still generates branchless code (e.g. cmoveq)).

@CraigEstey It is quite expected that constexpr if guarantees this, but thanks for the comment anyway. Rather, my question is caused by uncertainty about the correctness of understanding the rvalue reference

I don't understand what fails with the unconditional code(except the forgotten return). But your snippet can cause UB in senarios where T had members of reference type( similar to result of std::tie or std::forward_as_tuple).

@Red.Wave Thanks for the comment. I really forgot to return. About UB, I'm starting to explore this issue.

I don't see a way to avoid if constexpr before C++23's std::forward_like becomes available, but you could slightly simplify the implementation:
template<class F, class T>
decltype(auto) apply1(F&& func, T&& val) {
    auto& [m1] = val;
    if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T&&>)
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), m1);
    else
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), std::move(m1));
}

You don't need std::forward in the else branch because you already know the value category of (perfectly forwarded) val.
Demo

Could you briefly explain why we use structured binding with only one ampersand anyway?

@PavelDev You take value category from (forwarded) val anyway, && won't change anything. Keep in mind that val itself is always lvalue.
