Structured binding, passing them to other functions and value categories
The main question I have is:
How do you correctly write a function which applies structured binding and passes the resulting variables to a function, whilst correctly preserving references, const-ness, etc...
In Code
template<?>
<?> call_with( ? && object, ? && function ){
    auto ? [ x1, x2, x3 ] = ?( object );
    return ?( (?(function))( ?(x1), ?(x2), ?(x3) );
}

In this context I have the following smaller questions
(1), What difference does auto [ x1, x2, x3 ] = ... vs auto & [ x1, x2, x3 ] = ... vs auto && [ x1, x2, x3 ] = ... actually have. In this context which should be used?
(2), if object is passed as an rvalue, does it make sence to treatx1, x2 and x3 as rvalues as well? ( for possible types they could have T, T &, T &&, T const &, etc. ).
Does something similar hold for lvalues and how would this be implemented?
(3), What would the "correct" typing of function be? In the example I put it as an forwarding reference.
(4) Do any other operations need to be applied?

moving or forwarding object before the structured binding declaration
similarly for function
similarly for the return value of function

(5) How do I define the return type without loosing potential references returned by function?

Too many questions..

One question per post.

The question is the one stated at the beginning, the others are a request for answers to go in further details about those aspects, such that I can understand the solution better.

The question is still unclear. Give a clear example of what do you want to do and where you see a problem

Are you looking for implementation of std::apply?

@Jarod42 std apply only works for tuple like objects, and not every object which can be used for structured binding is tuple like. But in general I'm am looking for something similar to the implementation of std::apply but which works with structured binding. Additionally I also would like to understand the implementation.

template <class T, class F> decltype(auto) call_with(T&& object, F&& function) { auto&&[x1, x2, x3] = std::forward<T>(object); return std::forward<F>(function)(std::forward<decltype(x1)>(x1), std::forward<decltype(x2)>(x2), std::forward<decltype(x3)>(x3)); } perhaps?

@TedLyngmo , void test( Object & obj ){ call_with( obj, []< typename ... Ts >( Ts && ... ts ){} ); } seems to be passing members such as int x; as rvalues which seem strange, I would expect that when passing the member originating from an lvalue it would in turn also be an lvalue.

@SamCoutteau please show the definition of Object

For example struct Object{ int x; int y; int z; }; @TedLyngmo

Looks like a dupe for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78530873.

@TedLyngmo This won't preserve value category correctly. decltype(x1) will always be a non-reference type no matter what value category object has.

@Evg in the solution you linked if you pass a struct struct X { int & x; }; as an rvalue reference X &&  to apply1, the member seems to get passed as an rvalue reference int &&. Is this correct? I would expect that an lvalue reference member of an rvalue would stay as an lvalue reference.

No, it is limited to non-reference members. If you have references, you need more complicated logic.

@Evg Then I wouldn't say it is a duplicate, as I specifically ask to also consider the reference member case in (2).

The answer depends on a particular use case. In some cases you can treat such members as rvalues and in some cases you can't. In general you can't do it, it is not safe. But on the other hand, if you always treat them as lvalues, you might miss some optimizations provided by move semantics.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728626

Preface
This answer is made to be consistent with std::apply, such that the elements of a tuple are forwarded in the same way by std::apply and call_with. This seems like the most sensible way of approaching this problem as both function act similar, but use a different mechanism ( tuple-like vs structured binding ).
Solution
template< typename T, typename U >
struct copy_cref { using type = U; };
template< typename T, typename U >
struct copy_cref< T &, U > { using type = U &; };
template< typename T, typename U >
struct copy_cref< T const &, U > { using type = U const &; };
template< typename T, typename U >
struct copy_cref< T &&, U > { using type = U &&; };
template< typename T, typename U >
struct copy_cref< T const &&, U > { using type = U const &&; };

template<typename T,typename U>
using copy_cref_t = typename copy_cref<T,U>::type;

template< typename F, typename T >
constexpr decltype(auto) call_with( F && f, T && t )
{
    auto && [ x1, x2, x3, x4 ] = t;

    return std::invoke( 
        std::forward< F >( f ),
        std::forward< copy_cref_t< decltype( t ), decltype( x1 ) > >( x1 ),
        std::forward< copy_cref_t< decltype( t ), decltype( x2 ) > >( x2 ),
        std::forward< copy_cref_t< decltype( t ), decltype( x3 ) > >( x3 ),
        std::forward< copy_cref_t< decltype( t ), decltype( x4 ) > >( x4 )
    );
}

Explanation
std::apply
If we look at the exposition-only implementation of std::apply
template<class F,class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
constexpr decltype(auto)
    apply-impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>) // exposition only
{
    return INVOKE(std::forward<F>(f), std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}

We see that the elements are passed to INVOKE by using std::get on the forwarded tuple. The declarations of std::get, relevant here, are
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...>>::type& get( tuple<Types...>& t ) noexcept;

template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...>>::type&& get( tuple<Types...>&& t ) noexcept;

template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
const std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...>>::type& get( const tuple<Types...>& t ) noexcept;

template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
const std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...>>::type&& get( const tuple<Types...>&& t ) noexcept;

Observe that const and references are simply transferred from the tuple type to the element type. Unlike std::forward_like, which first removes references and then sets the reference, this uses the reference collapsing rules, T && & -> T &. This is the behaviour implemented by copy_cref.
For the specific questions I had.
(1) I still have not found I satisfactory explanation for the difference. It seems that auto && [...] is the most general version.
(2) The approach that std::apply takes seems to be the safest option. I would assume problems arise when you store lvalue and rvalue references to data stored within the same struct / tuple. The answer is thus "it depends".
(3,4,5) No idea, I simply copied std::apply. See the related resources.
Related Resources
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get 
Do structured bindings and forwarding references mix well? 
When to use std::invoke instead of simply calling the invokable? 
What is the difference between auto and decltype(auto) when returning from a function?
